# Problem when downloading Google CRMint: AttributeError: module 'appcli' has no attribute 'entry_point'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-shell-editor

I am trying to install CRMint following these instructions: https://google.github.io/crmint/docs/quickstart/cloudshell.md

When I tried to run to check if I have installed it

```
crmint --help
```

The following error appeared

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/crmint/.venv/bin/crmint", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('crmint', 'console_scripts', 'crmint')())
  File "/home/user/crmint/.venv/bin/crmint", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/metadata.py", line 79, in load
    return functools.reduce(getattr, attrs, module)
AttributeError: module 'appcli' has no attribute 'entry_point'
```

Could someone help me on that? Thank you in advance.

I tried uninstalling and installing 'appcli', but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This was around the same time that CRMint was upgraded to it's newest architecture, [CRMint 3.0](https://github.com/google/crmint/commit/74b4268aee1dc4bd55f0042f1c964e1a41d46ef0). This was a temporary bug that was impacting deployment, however, the current architecture deployment has been tested and should be working quiet reliably.

Sorry for the inconvenience. Let me know if you have other questions!

Comment: I followed the instructions again but it is still crmint 2.0. May I know where I can download CRMint 3.0? Also, I received the error "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable" when trying to run "crmint --help" Thanks!

Comment: You can download CRMint 3.0 from the master branch. Here are the instructions: https://github.com/google/crmint/blob/master/docs/docs/quickstart/simple.md